# Add a new button under "Home" Tab in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a new button under Fill color in Home tab in excel

I have tried adding my button by going to File > Option > Customize Ribbon but the options are disabled

I want to add my button in "Home" tab

Comment: It is not possible to customize built-in groups or controls in an Office Ribbon. You cannot "add a new button under Fill color", so the options to do so will not be enabled. This is by design. You can create new tabs and new groups with custom controls - and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting way of customizing the ribbon in excel (still works in Excel 2016) : 
https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm

In brief, with the help of CustomUI you will modify part of the file archive in the way that you can remove actual tabs, add your own tab, and custom buttons inside of it

You asked for adding a button in the "Home" tab, a workaround would be recreating "Home" tab in a personnal ribbon tab and adding your own button to it. Your personnal button could trigger a macro sub (VBA) or even use native Excel functionalities.

(I can help you further if you choose this way)

Comment: Basically 2nd approach is to add all existing functionalities of Home in a new tab and add my functionality in it as well?